# How to do a custom config file in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I'm trying to get values from database and pass to the custom settings.php file, in laravel 4, I could set values from a model: $settings = Setting::find(1); But in laravel 5.3 the config folder It's out app folder.
What is the best way to get the values and pass to settings.php file?
Maybe adding a service provider? How can I do that?

class SettingServiceProvider...

```
public function register()
{
    $settings = Setting::find(1);
    Config::set('settings.company', $settings->company);
    return $settings;
}
```

Maybe writing in the .env? But if the user wants to update these values, how can I update .env from an user interface?

Help please!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example I used in `middleware` to connect with Database

I have created the `Config` middleware and uses that in routes. In my case, I am having multi tenant application, and I am sure it will help you for case as well. **Example is**:

### Create Middleware named `Config`

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use App\Sites;
use Closure;

class config
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $site_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

        $site = Sites::where('site_url',$site_url)->first();

        $config = array();        

        if(!is_null($site)){

            $config['id'] = $site["id"];
            $config['site_url'] = $site["site_url"];
            $config['theme'] = $site["theme"];
            $config['host'] = $site["host"];
            $config['db_name'] = $site["database"];
            $config['user'] = $site["user"];
            $config['password'] = $site["password"];
            $config['prefix'] = $site["prefix"];

        }else{
 //default values
            $config['id'] = "0";
            $config['site_url'] = "demo.local";
            $config['theme'] = "theme";
            $config['host'] = "localhost";
            $config['db_name'] = "dbname";
            $config['user'] = "username";
            $config['password'] = "password";
            $config['prefix'] = "tbl";           
        }    
        //dd($config);
        // \Session::put('config', $config);

        \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.host', $config['host'] );
        \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $config['db_name'] );
        \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', $config['user']);
        \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', $config['password']);
        \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.prefix', $config['prefix']);

        \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.theme', $config['theme']);

        \DB::reconnect();

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now in routes, where you want to apply that configurations, do as follow

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'config'],function (){
       Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'HomeController@page']);
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Finally I've added an Artisan command to write and update the .env file, so everytime  user changes the settings data, I call this command, Artisan::call('update:settings'); from the SettingsController. I like this way because the data is storing in a static file.
public function update($id){
 $settings = Setting::find($id);
 $settings->update();
 Artisan::call('update:settings');
}
Anyway, your option is very good, maybe I will use something like this in the master application, to access to multiple web apps.
Thanks again for your answer!